# A pause/resume for my music command similar to my code?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, ytdl

Hello I am working on my music command. I already have a !play, !skip and !stop command but I want to make it so I can have a pause and resume command. Any Idea how to do that?
Any form of help will be appreciated

Also I am very new to coding so please help me in baby steps
here is my code

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const yts = require("yt-search");
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}plays`)) {
        execute(message, serverQueue).catch((_err) =>{
            message.channel.send('I was not able to fulfill your request')
        })
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}skips`)) {
        skip(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}stops`)) {
        stop(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } 
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
        );
    
    let song;
    if (ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
        song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.video_url
        };
    } else {
        const { videos } = await yts(args.slice(1).join(" "));
        if (!videos.length) return message.channel.send("No songs were found!");
        song = {
            title: videos[0].title,
            url: videos[0].url
        };
    }

    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true
        };

        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

        queueContruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueContruct.connection = connection;
            play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(err);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
    }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
    if (!serverQueue)
        return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
    serverQueue.songs = [];
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
    message.channel.send('Succesfully stopped all songs')
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
        .play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on("finish", () => {
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Started playing: **${song.title}**`);
}



bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase;

});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
        );
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.bot.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
        return message.channel.send(
            "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
        );
    }
    let song;
    if (ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
        song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.video_url
        };
    } else {
        const { videos } = await yts(args.slice(1).join(" "));
        if (!videos.length) return message.channel.send("No songs were found!");
        song = {
            title: videos[0].title,
            url: videos[0].url
        };
    }

    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true
        };

        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

        queueContruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueContruct.connection = connection;
            play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(err);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
    }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
    if (!serverQueue)
        return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
    serverQueue.songs = [];
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
        .play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on("finish", () => {
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}
```

And Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to make a Dispatcher like so:

```
let dispatcher = connection.play(song)
```

and the in the pause function, do

```
dispatcher.pause()
```

and for resume

```
dispatcher.resume()
```

Comment: can you please mark my answer correct? its the little grey check mark pls lol

Comment: Do you know how to change volume. Like !volume 1 or something @OctagonalT

Comment: yep, just do `dispatcher.setVolume(number)`